# Vuetify color picker hidden bar

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

In my project I use a `v-color-picker` like in doc https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/color-pickers/#canvas.

My code is

```
<v-color-picker v-model="color"/>
```

This seems to be ok, but when it renders, the color bar is hidden (?) like you can see in image (the bar should be at the right of the green circle).

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: You've probably got a CSS conflict. In the version I'm using, it uses a `background` rule with a linear gradient on the `.v-color-picker__hue` element. Use your element inspector to check and see if that rule is being overridden by accident.

Comment: @DavidK.Hess found, thanks